# ERD one table to many tables relationships

Tags: database-design, uml, data-modeling, erd

I'm creating an ERD and a certain parts give me headaches.

My issue:
I have four entities: magazine, book, newspaper, and webpage.
Each entity has it's own attributes.

I want to take notes on each of those four sources. But a note can only refer to one of them. E.g. a note on a book, can't be a note on a magazine, newspaper, or webpage.
Also, it should be possible to make multiple notes on a magazine, book, newspaper, or webpage.

After a couple of days of trial and error and searching the web and old fashioned books, I still can't find a way how to model this.

I think I need to use a N-ary association for this, but I am not really sure.
Can someone help me out? How should this be modeled?

On a side note: I'm using Enterprise Architect for modelling.

EDIT:
While thinking things over and thinking over the answers and comments, I created this ERD:

[image: ERD]

This feels like what I need, but in this case I think it is still possible to have 1 note to be tied to a magazine AND a book (AND a newspaper AND a website). Those ANDs should be ORs.

Hopefully this clarifies things a bit more. And hopefully I have the multiplicities correct (been looking at this too long, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a supertype (let's call it publications) on which you can hang your notes.  We can include a mutual exclusion restriction to prevent a publication from playing more than one role.

I realize you asked how to model it but instead of a diagram I'll give you SQL DDL.  My modeling tool won't let me set up the foreign key for magazines correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE publications (
    publication_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    publication_type ENUM('M','B','N','W') NOT NULL,
    KEY id_type (publication_id, publication_type)
);

CREATE TABLE magazines (
    publication_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    publication_type ENUM('M') NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (publication_id, publication_type)
    REFERENCES publications (publication_id, publication_type)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE notes (
    note_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    publication_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (publication_id)
    REFERENCES publications (publication_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The enum ('M', 'B', 'N', 'W') is meant to distinguish between magazines, books, newspapers and webpages.  I didn't show the tables for the last three, they're similar to the schema for magazines.

Some notes about entity-relationship terminology.  First, relationships are between entities (and stored in tables), not between tables as your heading states.  Second, tables have columns, while attributes are one-to-one associations between entities and values and represented by pairs of columns in a table.

EDIT:

A similar technique, but easier to implement after a database has been populated, is to create a new entity type to act as a container for notes, and incorporate them into your original entities where required.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE notables (
    notable_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE magazines (
    magazine_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    notable_id INT(11) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (notable_id)
    REFERENCES notables (notable_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE notes (
    note_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    notable_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (notable_id)
    REFERENCES notables (notable_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

In this case it's not as easy to enforce mutual exclusion, i.e. a notable_id could in theory be reused.

Comment: I guess I had my head to much in it. I know tables have columns and relations are between entities.
The way I have been thinking about this, is that instead of publications, I would have a table called note_to_entity (or note_to_publication, or whatever) which actually links a row in table note between a row in either table Magazine, Book, Newspaper or Website.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but somehow - can't exactly tell why, but I think it has to do with the publication_type column, which I don't like - I have a feeling your solution is not what I am looking for.
But then again, I am known to complicate things for myself and a type column might be the only/correct solution for this. In that case, the question arises: why should the type column also be in each of the tables M, B, N, and W? I already know it is about that table because I have the type.

Comment: It's a technique used to enforce mutually exclusive subtypes.  It prevents one from inserting rows into two subtype tables (e.g. magazines and books) for the same entity (publication_id) since the foreign key constraint must match on id as well as type, and only one type can be recorded in the row in the publications table.

Comment: @philipxy since you reference me here, please read my comment below in my answer :-)

Comment: @MichaelAlbers & reaanb: The 1st design doesn't *need* publication_type. The 2nd design doesn't *need* both notable_id *and* ids for each publication type. And neither design *needs* a table of publication/notable ids. (It's just the union of the ids in the separate tables,) It's just that most SQL DBMSs do not support the easy expression of most constraints but adding redundant columns and/or tables can allow (some) constraining via simple supported constraints like FKs. (Nb it's pointed out that the enums do this & that the 2nd design is an example of adding it to a prior note-free design.)

Comment: Martin Fowler has a good presentation of "Class Table Inheritance" which is basically the same technique as the one presented here.  Implementing your own inheritance ought to be taught in database 101, but it typically is not.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Maybe you make things too complicated. If all notes belong to single entities only they are clearly just properties of that entity. Else there is no reason to make them an entity on their own.

If you really need a `Notes` entity you would model your requirements like this:
[image]

**Edit** The `0..1` multiplicity was meant to be `0..n` by the OP. The relations would not change in any else aspect, though.

Comment: Michael said it should be possible to make multiple notes on magazines, books, newspaper, or webpages.

Comment: The thing is, an entity can have 0..* notes.
This is why I think I need a N-ary association, but when transforming the ERD to a data model (within EA), it just doesn't seem right.

Or would a disjoint - possibly combined with an N-ary association - be an option? When I check the example on http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/model_transformation/erd_to_data_modeling.html or in the EA example file, a disjoint looks like what I want. Although, if a disjoint could be one or both of the 'options', it is not what I need.

Comment: @reaanb actually Michael did no specifically say anything about `0..n` (except you read 'notes' as this plural). But obviously he did mean `0..n`. Michael: I'll have a look at the link.

Comment: Just  looked at the example. I haven't used DB design in EA for a long time. But I guess the transformation would add a foreign key for each referenced class to `Notes`.  You would need to adapt the constraint manually like in the 1st example of @reaanb where you have an enum that tells which id the (single) foreign key refers to. Generally there is more than one way to implement the `XOR` constraint. It always depends on the other requirements/constraints we don't know here.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Your 2nd approach is possible but as a DB designer I would prefer a simple ID property in `Notes` along with a flag which maps to either of your base classes (like in @reaanb's first approach). The additional table does not makes things clearer/more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. In that case my notes_to_entity table/entity is equal to @reaanb's publication table when I add an column/attribute to the notes_to_entity table table/entity. At least, if I understand correctly.
And would be best to use an enum column? Or just a varchar and set the options somewhere else in the application?

Comment: I would use a (var)char as flag and an integer (or what you use as primary key type for you main classes). With that your logic would be very simple. To get the notes you would select those with the same ID and the correct flag. That's it.